# In pandas (>1.0), how to convert dtype of a float series with missing values to integer?

Tags: python, pandas

Converting `Series` dtypes is easy:

`s = pd.Series([1.1, 2.2]).astype(int)`

However, if the `Series contains a`pd.NA` (N/A value), the conversion breaks

`s = pd.Series([1.1, 2.2, pd.NA]).astype(int)`

Results in `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NAType'`

Despite the fact, that we can store missing values in `Series` of ints

`s = pd.Series([1, 2, pd.NA]).astype(pd.Int64Dtype())`

Comment: can you first `fillna(0)` and then converting the dtype or is 0 an important value?

Comment: @mrbTT 0 is important

Comment: Maybe replace for another integer number that you're sure you're not gonna use and than replace for NaN. But that will change the column's dtype to float. NaNs cant be integers.

Comment: @mrbTT The actual question is, how did a `pd.NA` end up in a series of dtype float. Pandas represents those as `np.nan`. If the list contained a `np.nan` there would be no problem with type casting since you can safely do `s.round().astype('Int64')` for example. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Hey @a_guest, if I'm not mistaken, since the - recently - release of pandas 1.0, they instated that null values would be represented by pd.NA now, and now np.nan.

Comment: @mrbTT As [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na) state, `pd.NA` is an experimental feature that is used only *"in the nullable integer, boolean and dedicated string data types as the missing value indicator"*. For `float` values nothing has changed so far and they are still represented by `np.nan` - as ever. If you convert between `float -> int64 -> float` it will perform the conversion `np.nan -> pd.NA -> np.nan` correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is a workaround or an actual solution, but one way to solve this problem is to `round` the values (or use `ceiling` or `floor`), followed by conversion do `pd.Int64Dtype()` (which refuses to convert non-integer values)

```
s = pd.Series([1.1, 2.2, None])
s.round().astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Comment: In your question you used `pd.NA` while here in the answer you use `None` (while pandas still uses `np.nan` as the default). What you propose doesn't work with `pd.NA` though (the question is how you got a `pd.NA` in the first place).

Comment: Originally, the data is read from a csv file, and it can have some missing values

Comment: If parsed via `pd.read_csv` missing data will be filled with `np.nan` not `None` or `pd.NA`. However in neither your question nor answer you mention `np.nan` so I really wonder how your data ends up containing either `pd.NA` or `None`.